# Add tag to launch template for ec2 nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-auto-scaling

I am trying to add tags to a launch template so that the ec2 nodes are tagged and named..

When I add the hardcoded tags inside the module it works, but the idea is to have dynamic tags and be able to merge with the local ones.

```
module
```

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_asg" {
  name                      = var.name_asg
  max_size                  = var.max_size
  min_size                  = var.min_size
  .
  .
  .
  service_linked_role_arn   = var.service_linked_role_arn
  tags = var.asg_tags
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}
```

```
variables.tf
```

```
variable "asg_tags" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {}
}
```

```
main.tf
```

```
  name_asg                  = "leo-nombre-asg"
  max_size                  = var.max_size
  min_size                  = var.min_size
  .
  .
  .
  asg_tags = merge(
    local.tags,
    {
      propagate_at_launch=true,
    },
  )
```

```
locals.tf
```

```
locals {
       tags = {
        "Accountable" = "business"
        "Deploy"      = "terraform"
        "Role"        = "services"
    }
}
```

```
terraform validate
```

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on modules\ecs\main.tf line 38, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_asg":
│   38:   tags = var.asg_tags
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.asg_tags is a map of string
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": set of map of string required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two fixes necessary here are both for the type in the `asg_tags` parameter argument value:

```
asg_tags = [merge(local.tags, { "propagate_at_launch" = "true" })]
```

Here we use the `list/set` constructor to cast the type `set(map(string))`. Terraform will coerce to `set` instead of `list` with the constructor as long as the type is specified to be `set` instead. Since we need to fix the type declaration anyway to be compatible with the resource attribute schema, this is convenient to do:

```
variable "asg_tags" {
  type = set(map(string))
  default = {}
}
```